# Replacement for HTML form with a huge list

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I want the user to select an item from over 700 possible choices. I cannot use select tag because the page will be so heavy!
These are my possible solutions but I don't know how to implement them:

1. A textbox with ajax autocomplete that allows only defined words. something like tags.
2. A huge list that fills using ajax!!!

**Using PHP**

What's your suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-list

Comment: you can also load data on demand (on scrolling for instance). not the best choice, but just another option. check this out https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxComboBox/CallbackMode.aspx

Comment: Thanks. but how can I do it with PHP?

Comment: I'd do a auto complete that gets suggestions after 2/3 letters are typed via an ajax call

Comment: Is there any JQuery widgets ? How can I implement such thing?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step it also has the php code example